# Assign specific data from a string response to a variable

Tags: python

My code:

```
#Importing the urllib tool to my program
import urllib.request

#Fetch data from URL
response = urllib.request.urlopen('<URL>')

#Store that response into the variable below
taginfo = response.read()

#Tag info result of search for SSI values
taginforesult = taginfo

#print taginfo
print(taginfo)
```

The result of the above in Python Shell is correct as follows:

```
b'LOCATE00016331: tagid="00016331", taggroupid=LOCATE, tagtype=mantis04A, irlocator=null, motion=false, tamper=false, panic=false, lowbattery=false, locationzone="", gpsid="", lastgpsid="", lastgpsts=null, confidencebyrule={}\r\n(CarrierHQ_channel_A: reader=CarrierHQ, channel="A", ssi=-95)\r\n(CarrierHQ_channel_B: reader=CarrierHQ, channel="B", ssi=-99)\r\n\r\n\r\n'
```

What I want is to know is: how do I select only the `SSI=-95` and `SSI-99` values from the response above and then insert them to an `SSI-A` and `SSI-B` variable?

Do I `strip()`, `findall()`, `search()`, ...?

Comment: Which of ideas you mention did you try? What was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a strange format. But you can easily cut it up to get the parts you want.

```
ssia = str(taginfo).split("\\r\\n")[1]
                   .strip("()")
                   .split(",")[-1]
                   .strip()
                   .split("=")[1]
assert ssia == '-95'

ssib = str(taginfo).split("\\r\\n")[2]
                   .strip("()")
                   .split(",")[-1]
                   .strip()
                   .split("=")[1]    
assert ssib == '-99'
```

Comment: Would you know how to make the program run another URL in the event of either 'ssia' or 'ssib' value being less than -100 (ie: -110)?

Comment: Run another URL? Do you want to `urllib.request.urlopen` a different URL if `int(ssia) < 100 or int(ssib) < 100`?

Comment: This should be easy. I've already given you the answer in my last comment :)

Comment: wait sorry, I am initially doing a:
urllib.request.urlopen

then as above, stripping to get the SSI values from it

Now I want the program to check the SSI value on ssia and ssib and if ssia or ssib are < -100 then urlopen(http:// ... ... ...)

Comment: oh Yes I see what you mean :), your time and assistance is greatly appreciated.